# Learning vector quantization doesn't work well in matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification

I want to use learning vector quantization (LVQ) to classify F_CK data with 7 classes. 
When I use MLP, error is about 15% . but when I use LVQ, error is about 75% :(
I see that LVQ only classifies one class very good but doesn't classify other classes.

my code:

```
data = load('F_CK+');
x = data.X';
y_data = data.Y';
t = ind2vec(y_data);    
net = lvqnet(4,0.1,'learnlv2');
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand'; 
net.divideMode = 'sample';  
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 85/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 0/100;
net.trainParam.epochs = 15;
net = train(net, x, t);
y = net(x);
classes = vec2ind(y);
figure, plotconfusion(t,y);
```

confusion matrix of my result.

[image]

FC_K

Can any one help me, why this network only classify one class and what is my fault ?

dataset link:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100069389/File/Stackoverflow/F_CK.rar

https://mega.nz/#!J8ES1DRS!NZwDsD0FFojeZiI-OpORzxGLbMp9rx0XKsfOvGDOaR0

Comment: It also may depend which version of LVQ matlab uses. Most of the libaries in various languages prefer LVQ2 because it hits the sweet spot between accuracy and simpilicity, Multiclass classification is a bit tricky with LVQ2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is my fault but I do something that improve the accuracy of classification. 
1. normalize data between -1 and 1
2. increase the subclasses/ LVQ neurons to 64 to cover all of image class.

as far as I'm remembered, the LVQ network must more accurate than MLP, but my accuracy with LVQ is increased to 80%.